# Unresolved dependency on sbt-android-plugin 0.6.0-SNAPSHOT?

Tags: android, scala, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I just followed the steps at [Build Scala Android apps using Scala](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin#build-scala-android-apps-using-scala) and when I ran `sbt` inside the project folder I got the following unresolved dependency error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/macarse/Documents/scalatest/project/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/macarse/Documents/scalatest/project/plugins/}default-dd299a...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1/0.6.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn]   -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT!sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1.jar:
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1/0.6.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1.jar
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/macarse/.ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1/0.6.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn]   -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT!sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1.jar:
[warn]   /Users/macarse/.ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1/0.6.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1.jar
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1/0.6.0-SNAPSHOT/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]   -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT!sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1.jar:
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1/0.6.0-SNAPSHOT/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[warn] ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried
[warn]   http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1/0.6.0-SNAPSHOT/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]   -- artifact org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT!sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1.jar:
[warn]   http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/sbt/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1/0.6.0-SNAPSHOT/sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/Users/macarse/Documents/scalatest/project/plugins/}default-dd299a/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For sbt 0.11.0:

1. Follow instructions from [@Debilski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561723/unresolved-dependency-when-creating-application-with-the-sbt-plugin-for-android-d/7562435#7562435) to publish android-plugin to local.
2. `rm -rvf project/plugins/`
3. Create a file `project/plugins.sbt`, the content of this file is `addSbtPlugin("org.scala-tools.sbt" % "sbt-android-plugin" % "0.6.0-SNAPSHOT")`
4. Now you should be able to run `sbt` under that project
5. `android:package-debug` to compile/package the hello world program g8 created.
6. `android:install-device` to install the APK on the android device.

Comment: @Macarse In facts I don't know what happened exactly, I'm not quite familiar with SBT 0.1x. I just found in error message that the project searches for android-plugin.jar in location that different from publish-local publish to in the step 1. So I search on the SBT official document for another way to include a plugin in project, and found this one works. That's all, just trail and error and have no idea why.

Answer (score 3):

`sbt-android-plugin` has not been made public in version `0.6.0-SNAPSHOT`. A quick fix would be to install it locally.

```
git clone https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin.git 
cd android-plugin
sbt update
sbt publish-local
```

Of course, this works only as long as the github repository’s master branch points to version `0.6.0-SNAPSHOT`. (If it doesn’t anymore, then I may suspect that `0.6.0` has been published.)

Comment: I did that but I am still getting the same issue. Inside android-plugin I write `version` and I get `[info] 0.6.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.  After following suggested steps successfully, sbt android:package-debug still gives [error] {file:/C:/Workspaces/my-android-project/project/plugins/}default-949520/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt-android-plugin_2.9.1;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

Comment: the way plugins get added has changhed in sbt 0.11. for now use `g8 jberkel/android-app -b sbt-0_11` to initialise your project.

Comment: To clarify @JanBerkel's comment, you still need to do the publish local as described here and then create your project with g8 jberkel/android-app -b sbt-0_11